# Forward process fail in ONNX model

Tags: c++, opencv, onnx

I want to use [FER+ Emotion Recognition](https://github.com/onnx/models/tree/master/vision/body_analysis/emotion_ferplus) in my project:

```
string modelPath = "../data/model.onnx";
Mat frame = imread("../data/Smile-Mood.jpg");

Mat gray;
cvtColor(frame, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

float scale = 1.0;
int inHeight = 64;
int inWidth = 64;
bool swapRB = false;

//Read and initialize network
cv::dnn::Net net = cv::dnn::readNetFromONNX(modelPath);

Mat blob;
//Create a 4D blob from a frame
cv::dnn::blobFromImage(gray, blob, scale, Size(inWidth, inHeight), swapRB, false);

//Set input blob
net.setInput(blob);

//Make forward pass
Mat prob = net.forward();
```

I have this error in last line:

`Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFDA25AA799 in FERPlusDNNOpenCV.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00000063839BE050. occurred`

`OpenCV(4.1.0) Error: Assertion failed (ngroups > 0 && inpCn % ngroups == 0 && outCn % ngroups == 0) in cv::dnn::ConvolutionLayerImpl::getMemoryShapes`

how to fix that?

**UPDATE ACCORDING @Micka COMMENT**:

```
Mat dstImg = Mat(64, 64, CV_32FC1);

resize(gray, dstImg, Size(64, 64));

std::vector<float> array;
if (dstImg.isContinuous())
    array.assign(dstImg.data, dstImg.data + dstImg.total());
else{
    for (int i = 0; i < dstImg.rows; ++i) {
        array.insert(array.end(), dstImg.ptr<float>(i), dstImg.ptr<float>(i) + dstImg.cols);
    }
}

//Set input blob
net.setInput(array);

//Make forward pass
Mat prob = net.forward();
```

I've got this error: `vector subscript out of range.`

Should I use another function instead `setInput`?

Comment: Are you sure the input image for ```blobFromImage``` should be in gray? If you get your code snippet from somewhere, can you share the link?

Comment: dont use blobFromImage for grayscale images. You have to use setBlob function instead. https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/1184

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk ,[this](https://gallery.azure.ai/Model/FER-Emotion-Recognition) says to use gray image, but it is not different. when i use color image, I've got this error too.

Comment: @Micka What is the main differences between those 2 functions?

Comment: blob has a different pixel order (channel-wise instead of pixel-wise) than images. For a single channel input, blob conversion isnt necessary, so the function might not he necessary.

Comment: @Saeid: What's the input neuron number of your network? if it is W x H then W x H x 3 input doesnt make sense (and blob converted 4-dim image neither)

Comment: @Micka , yes, you're right. i think like you so i've written another code but i've got another error. i update my question please see that.

Comment: in the link i posted they say to use Net::setBlob(), but the posting is from 2017. Maybe search for opencv dnn grayscale blob or sth...

Comment: readNetFromONNX doesn't work for me, how did you use it. Can you please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69633595/load-onnx-model-in-opencv-dnn ?